# PHP Based Website Using Weka As The Engine

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, weka, data-mining

I would like to develop a php based web application, preferably using MySQL and CodeIgniter PHP Framework. I've never used Weka before, but my assignment requires me to connect Weka to PHP.

The plan is to develop a dashboard (using php) which is going to be used by the school administrator. They won't have to interact with weka, since they are going to use the dashboard only.

When they enter the student data, php will send the data to weka and weka will perform data mining on the data. Once it finishes processing the data, the result will be returned back to php and displayed in the front end.

I have done a lot of Google to understand how to solve this problem, but most of the answers they provided are dead links or didn't offer much help.

Please help and thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also have done my project analysis in weka front end used in asp.net. my opinion you just convert your datas to CSV file and attach to the weka analyse it.I hope it will be easier to you.